# WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state Socket io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Socket io returning error as:
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state Socket io.

Node JS:

```
socket.to(socketId).emit('details', { userdetails: username });
```

React JS:

```
socket.on('details', data => {
    console.log(data.userdetails);
});
```

Can you please help me to resolve issue of WebSocket is in closing or closed state.
Any kind of help is appreciable.

Comment: Any one has idea on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a change for the default pingTimeout from 60000 (v2.0.4) to 5000 (v2.1.0+) which is not enough for some browsers like Chrome.

The solution to this issue on v2.1.0+ including the latest v2.2.0 is to override the default pingTimeout on your server.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Roll back to socket.io-client version 2.0.3. There is an issue in the latest 2.1.1 version.

```
npm install socket.io-client@2.0.3 --save
```

2) Also, make sure you cleanup after yourself in React.js and close the socket...

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('http://www.example.com');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }
```